# Why is having a single process sort a list so much faster than having many processes sort separate lists of equal size?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp, multicore

I have 64 cores on a single machine running sorting on a total of 1GB of data. They each sort 156,250 items, and shouldn't be sharing any data structures (i.e. there are a total of 64 separate arrays being sorted). However the more cores I have running, the slower each core is at its own sorting task.

The time measurement is being done as such:

```
void sort_ranges(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > & range_partitions, int num_workers, std::string filename, std::string outfile)
{
  #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(range_partitions, outfile, num_workers)
  {
    int i = omp_get_thread_num();
    std::vector<int> data_vec; //Data copied into separate data structure for each thread
    for(int x = 0; x < num_workers; x ++) {
      data_vec.reserve(data_vec.size() + (range_partitions[x][i]).size());
      data_vec.insert(data_vec.end(), range_partitions[x][i].begin(), range_partitions[x][i].end());
    }
    int n = data_vec.size();
    int * data = &data_vec[0];
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    std::sort(data, data + n); //Measure sort function call
    double sort_done = omp_get_wtime() - start;
  }
}
```

When I run on 1GB of data, each process sorts a size 156,250 array and takes about 10 seconds. Obviously this is ridiculously slow. If I run one process that sorts a size 156,250 array, the process takes < 0.1 seconds to sort.

I'm really confused by this, because each process is running on a different array, so there's no reason having more cores running an identical task should slow down all the other cores.

I think there's something about how memory is managed that I'm missing. Any help is appreciated!

**I realize there are a lot of different costs for increased parallelism, e.g. process overhead or working on shared memory, however I am specifically concerned with the slowdown of the std::sort() function called on separate data structures for each thread**

Comment: Starting a process has an overhead. And you don't show how you are starting them.

Comment: why are you confused that reading 1GB takes longer than reading 156,250 bytes?

Comment: I think there could be many reasons for this mainly due to resource contention. A few examples are loading the files and also ram usage. Maybe your antivirus is also to blame. Plus it does take time to launch a new process.

Comment: Agreed. Many-many. Maybe even lots. Don't discount the slow-downs that will be incurred by many processes attempting to access the same data storage medium all at the same time.

Comment: I don't recognise the exact flavour of your omp dialect. Which parts of this code are you expecting will be run once, and which parts will be run in parallel? Check your assumptions?

Comment: Sorry I left out a couple things in the original question. The line `int i 
= omp_get_thread_num()` tells each process which part of the data to sort, which is then used to copy data into 'data_vec'. I did this to be extra sure that the processes were sorting separate arrays (i.e. the processes wont be accessing the same data while performing sort)

Comment: I also wanted to clarify that the performance times I am measuring is only measuring the time of `std::sort(data, data + n);` per process and nothing else. The `std::sort(data, data + n);` is by far the most time consuming part of my computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Total memory bandwidth is limited, when you have data bigger than your cache (and 1 GB of data is surely going out of your cache) and a bad access pattern (and sort generally is quite bad, especially the first steps) memory speed is going to be your limit. If you are already capping it with one core, sorting N copies of it in parallel is going to slow it down N times - possibly more as you are also thrashing the L3 cache (each core is trying to access unrelated data).

Comment: I think this interpretation is likely the correct one.

Comment: I couldn't find evidence of this, per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766171/752843).

Comment: If this is the case, what can I do to verify and/or fix the problem?

Comment: @swooders: Use fewer cores and try to pin processes to cores to ensure that they aren't pounding the same cache. See [this](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-affinity.html). I've edited my answer to include this info.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't include a [minimum working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) with your question, so I was not able to reproduce your issue.

I agree with other folks that likely what you're seeing is that using too many cores to do the sort results in [cache thrashing](https://www.quora.com/What-is-cache-thrashing), though I haven't been able to prove that based on my own tests.

When the CPU reads data from memory it doesn't just read one byte. It reads *many* bytes. These are stored in a cache for quick access. Caches are hierarchical and shared to greater or lesser degrees between processors, like so:

[image: Cache hierarchy]

As you can see, the cores all share the L3 cache. If the memory addresses the cores are operating on are distant from each other, the cores will have limited cache overlap and compete to utilize the cache.

Verifying whether or not this is happening in your code is easy (at least, if you have Linux). You can use the [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) [command](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) to gather data about what your program is doing.

At the bottom of this question, I include a MWE of what I think you're asking about. I then gather statistics about the behaviour of the MWE using the following `perf` command.

```
perf stat -e cache-misses,cache-references,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-stores,l2_rqsts.miss,LLC-load-misses,LLC-loads,LLC-prefetch-misses,LLC-store-misses,LLC-stores ./a.out m
```

This results in the following for single-threaded operation:

```
    18,676,838      cache-misses              #   69.492 % of all cache refs      (27.28%)
    26,876,349      cache-references                                              (36.38%)
   143,224,257      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    1.65% of all L1-dcache hits    (36.39%)
 8,682,532,168      L1-dcache-loads                                               (36.40%)
 4,130,005,905      L1-dcache-stores                                              (36.40%)
    92,709,572      l2_rqsts.miss                                                 (36.40%)
     2,409,977      LLC-load-misses           #   34.83% of all LL-cache hits     (36.39%)
     6,919,668      LLC-loads                                                     (36.37%)
    23,562,449      LLC-prefetch-misses                                           (18.16%)
    16,038,395      LLC-store-misses                                              (18.19%)
    79,580,399      LLC-stores                                                    (18.18%)

  24.578381342 seconds time elapsed
```

And for running with four threads:

```
    21,357,447      cache-misses              #   74.720 % of all cache refs      (23.99%)
    28,583,269      cache-references                                              (33.10%)
   160,265,596      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    1.85% of all L1-dcache hits    (35.91%)
 8,670,516,235      L1-dcache-loads                                               (36.52%)
 4,131,943,678      L1-dcache-stores                                              (36.50%)
   102,495,289      l2_rqsts.miss                                                 (36.50%)
     2,768,956      LLC-load-misses           #   38.05% of all LL-cache hits     (32.91%)
     7,277,568      LLC-loads                                                     (31.23%)
    29,220,858      LLC-prefetch-misses                                           (15.36%)
    18,920,533      LLC-store-misses                                              (15.26%)
   104,834,221      LLC-stores                                                    (14.85%)

  10.334248457 seconds time elapsed
```

As you can see, running with four threads did result in more cache misses for
me. This may not be a statistically-significant increase; I didn't run multiple
times to check. However, unlike you, I see improved performance with more
threads.

To simulate cache contention, I can oversubscribe my CPU by using more threads than cores. To do so, I set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=32
```

With 32 threads, I see:

Performance counter stats for './a.out m':

```
    24,222,105      cache-misses              #   77.175 % of all cache refs      (23.39%)
    31,385,891      cache-references                                              (32.47%)
   161,353,805      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    1.87% of all L1-dcache hits    (35.27%)
 8,618,074,931      L1-dcache-loads                                               (36.70%)
 4,131,633,620      L1-dcache-stores                                              (36.28%)
   107,094,632      l2_rqsts.miss                                                 (36.21%)
     5,299,670      LLC-load-misses           #   56.36% of all LL-cache hits     (31.93%)
     9,403,090      LLC-loads                                                     (29.02%)
    46,500,188      LLC-prefetch-misses                                           (15.09%)
    20,131,861      LLC-store-misses                                              (14.26%)
   105,310,438      LLC-stores                                                    (14.15%)

  10.379022550 seconds time elapsed
```

Notice that our LLC-load-misses (last level cache) has gone from 34% to 38% to
56% as the number of threads increases. Speed, however, is not much affected.
This may be because the data doesn't have good cache locality to begin with.

Regardless, this is one way to study your problem. If you want better help than
this, you'll have to make an MWE of your own.

You can alleviate some of the cache contention by reducing the number of threads you are using and specifying their affinity so that threads do not share the same L2/L3 caches (depending on your processor). More information is [here](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-affinity.html).

## Minimum Working Example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > data_t;

data_t GenData(std::mt19937 &mt_rand, int vec_num, int vec_len){
  data_t data;
  data.reserve(vec_num);
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<vec_num;i++){
    data.emplace_back();
    data.back().reserve(vec_len);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<vec_len;i++)
      data.back().emplace_back(mt_rand());
  }
  return data;
}

void SortSingle(data_t &data){
  for(auto &v: data)
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
}

void SortMulti(data_t &data){
  #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(data)
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
    std::sort(data[i].begin(), data[i].end());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::mt19937 mt_rand;

  typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;

  std::cout<<"Generating data..."<<std::endl;
  auto data = GenData(mt_rand,1600,156250);

  std::cout<<"Sorting data..."<<std::endl;
  const auto start_time = clock::now();
  if(argv[1][0]=='s')
    SortSingle(data);
  else if (argv[1][0]=='m')
    SortMulti(data);
  else
    std::cout<<"Unknown sort type!"<<std::endl;
  const auto end_time = clock::now();

  const auto time_diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(end_time - start_time).count();

  std::cout<<"Time = "<<time_diff<<"s"<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code leaves out a critical final brace.

I think the code you meant to write is as shown below.

```
void sort_ranges(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > & range_partitions, int num_workers, std::string filename, std::string outfile) {
  #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(range_partitions, outfile, num_workers)
  {
    std::vector<int> data_vec; //Data copied into separate data structure for each thread
    for(int x = 0; x < num_workers; x ++) {
      data_vec.reserve(data_vec.size() + (range_partitions[x][i]).size());
      data_vec.insert(data_vec.end(), range_partitions[x][i].begin(), range_partitions[x][i].end());
    }
    int n        = data_vec.size();
    int * data   = &data_vec[0];
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    std::sort(data, data + n); //Measure sort function call
    double sort_done = omp_get_wtime() - start;
  }
}
```

I think that your code doesn't do what you expect.

The `#pragma omp parallel` indicates that *every* thread should do the contents of your block.

The variable `i` doesn't appear in your code excerpt, so it's impossible to know what that does.

However, every thread appears to be copying a number of ranges into `data_vec`, after which every thread sorts the same data.

You might want to try this instead:

```
void sort_ranges(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > & range_partitions, int num_workers, std::string filename, std::string outfile) {
  #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(range_partitions, outfile)
  for(int x=0;x<num_workers;x++){
    std::vector<int> data_vec(range_partitions[x][i].begin(), range_partitions[x][i].end()); //Data copied into separate data structure for each thread
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    std::sort(data_vec.begin(), data_vec.end()); //Measure sort function call
    double sort_done = omp_get_wtime() - start;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was trying to simplify my code and took out too much - the i variable specified which part of range_partitions each process should be collecting their input, and I have print statements in my own code that shows each process is sorting an array with the size I expect.

Comment: @swooders: This is a good example of why you should use descriptive variable names. Had you used `task_num` instead of `i`, it would have been very clear what you meant. The best way to make code to put online is to make a new little program that reproduces the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

With parallel programming, there are a number of factors that must be taken into consideration.

First, you have the non-negligible startup cost (overhead) of creating separate threads/setting up multiple processes. For this reason, adding parallelism typically makes things run *less* efficiently unless you have sufficient data that running multiple threads will actually improve the overall runtime.

Secondly, these tasks must be scheduled onto the number of cores you have available. If you have 4 cores and 64 tasks, those 64 tasks need to be scheduled onto the cores - a nontrivial task if each task takes a different amount of time to complete.

Thirdly, if there is any interference between threads, then that can slow things down, especially with a large number of threads.

Additionally, there is the aspect of skew, where the slowest task is the bottleneck - until the slowest task finishes, the entire set of processes is not considered finished.

These are just some of the factors that should be taken into consideration.